# How to realize the slider with circular hollow handle in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

is there a way to implement the slide bar with a circular **hollow handle** in QT?

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with setting the handle to simply be hollow like that?

Comment: @hyde hi, if it is directly set to be hollow, you will see the groove below.

Comment: So you want the hollow part to "see through" the groove. If that's a hard requirement, you *may* have to implement your own drawing, by sublcassing `QAbstractScrollbar` or just `QScrollBar` (or if it is a QML ui, just do a custom scrollbar component in QML, not terribly hard and a good exercise in QML).

Comment: you want that in c++ or QML?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R QSlider belong to QtWidgets

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I want to implement it in c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After consulting the documentation on `QStyle`, I decided to use `QStyle` to redraw `QSlider` to achieve the desired effect. Here is the implementation code.

```py
# coding:utf-8
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QMouseEvent, QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QProxyStyle, QSlider, QStyle, QStyleOptionSlider,
                             QWidget)

class HollowHandleStyle(QProxyStyle):
    """ 滑块中空样式 """

    def __init__(self, config: dict = None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        config: dict
            样式配置
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.config = {
            "groove.height": 3,
            "sub-page.color": QColor(255, 255, 255),
            "add-page.color": QColor(255, 255, 255, 64),
            "handle.color": QColor(255, 255, 255),
            "handle.ring-width": 4,
            "handle.hollow-radius": 6,
            "handle.margin": 4
        }
        config = config if config else {}
        self.config.update(config)

        # 计算 handle 的大小
        w = self.config["handle.margin"]+self.config["handle.ring-width"] + \
            self.config["handle.hollow-radius"]
        self.config["handle.size"] = QSize(2*w, 2*w)

    def subControlRect(self, cc: QStyle.ComplexControl, opt: QStyleOptionSlider, sc: QStyle.SubControl, widget: QWidget):
        """ 返回子控件所占的矩形区域 """
        if cc != self.CC_Slider or opt.orientation != Qt.Horizontal or sc == self.SC_SliderTickmarks:
            return super().subControlRect(cc, opt, sc, widget)

        rect = opt.rect

        if sc == self.SC_SliderGroove:
            h = self.config["groove.height"]
            grooveRect = QRectF(0, (rect.height()-h)//2, rect.width(), h)
            return grooveRect.toRect()

        elif sc == self.SC_SliderHandle:
            size = self.config["handle.size"]
            x = self.sliderPositionFromValue(
                opt.minimum, opt.maximum, opt.sliderPosition, rect.width())
            # 解决滑块跑出滑动条的情况
            x *= (rect.width()-size.width())/rect.width()
            sliderRect = QRectF(x, 0, size.width(), size.height())
            return sliderRect.toRect()

    def drawComplexControl(self, cc: QStyle.ComplexControl, opt: QStyleOptionSlider, painter: QPainter, widget: QWidget):
        """ 绘制子控件 """
        if cc != self.CC_Slider or opt.orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return super().drawComplexControl(cc, opt, painter, widget)

        grooveRect = self.subControlRect(cc, opt, self.SC_SliderGroove, widget)
        handleRect = self.subControlRect(cc, opt, self.SC_SliderHandle, widget)
        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        # 绘制滑槽
        painter.save()
        painter.translate(grooveRect.topLeft())

        # 绘制划过的部分
        w = handleRect.x()-grooveRect.x()
        h = self.config['groove.height']
        painter.setBrush(self.config["sub-page.color"])
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, w, h)

        # 绘制未划过的部分
        x = w+self.config['handle.size'].width()
        painter.setBrush(self.config["add-page.color"])
        painter.drawRect(x, 0, grooveRect.width()-w, h)
        painter.restore()

        # 绘制滑块
        ringWidth = self.config["handle.ring-width"]
        hollowRadius = self.config["handle.hollow-radius"]
        radius = ringWidth + hollowRadius

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(0, 0)
        center = handleRect.center() + QPoint(1, 1)
        path.addEllipse(center, radius, radius)
        path.addEllipse(center, hollowRadius, hollowRadius)

        handleColor = self.config["handle.color"]  # type:QColor
        handleColor.setAlpha(255 if opt.activeSubControls !=
                             self.SC_SliderHandle else 153)
        painter.setBrush(handleColor)
        painter.drawPath(path)

        # 滑块按下
        if widget.isSliderDown():
            handleColor.setAlpha(255)
            painter.setBrush(handleColor)
            painter.drawEllipse(handleRect)
```

Here is an example about how to use `HollowHandleStyle`:

```py
# coding:utf-8
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider


class Demo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet("Demo{background: rgb(34, 180, 127)}")
        style = {
            "sub-page.color": QColor(70, 23, 180),
            "handle.ring-width": 4,
            "handle.hollow-radius": 6,
            "handle.margin": 4
        }
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setStyle(HollowHandleStyle(style))
        self.slider.resize(200, 28)
        self.slider.move(50, 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The following figure shows the final effect:

[image: slider]

Answer (score 3):

you can transparent background of Handel and set a border for it by **stylesheet** but in this way you will see a line of the slider, if you **choose the background color of the slider the same as its backend you can fix it by the stylesheet, else you should write it with paint and create your custom slider.**

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(52, 59, 72);
}
QSlider::groove:horizontal:hover {
    background-color: rgb(55, 62, 76);
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 4px solid black;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: -14px 0;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: -14px 0px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

**ui code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>561</width>
    <height>238</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSlider" name="horizontalSlider">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>70</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(52, 59, 72);
}
QSlider::groove:horizontal:hover {
    background-color: rgb(55, 62, 76);
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: -14px 0;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: -14px 0px;
}

</string>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>561</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```